# SQLite to Pandas - speed

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I recently swapped to Python from using SAS. I want to do some SQL queries in Python. I do them as follows (table1 and table2 are pandas dataframes):

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
sql = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c = sql.cursor()

table1.to_sql('table1sql', sql, if_exists='replace', index=False)
table2.to_sql('table2sql', sql, if_exists='replace', index=False)

df_sql = c.execute('''
                      SELECT a.*, b.*
                      FROM table1sql as a
                      LEFT JOIN table2sql as b
                      ON a.id = b.id

                      ''')

df = pd.DataFrame(df_sql.fetchall())
df.columns = list(map(lambda x: x[0], c.description)) # get column names from sql cursor
```

I work with very large datasets. Sometimes up to 60 mio observations. The query itself takes seconds. However, "fetching" the dataset, i.e. transforming the sql dataframe to a pandas dataframe, takes ages.

In SAS, the entire SQL query would take seconds. Is the way I am doing it inefficient? Is there any other way of doing what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

# Connect to sqlite3 instance
con = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')

# Read sqlite query results into a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_sql_query('''
    SELECT a.*, b.*
    FROM table1sql as a
    LEFT JOIN table2sql as b
    ON a.id = b.id
  ''',
  con
)

# Verify that result of SQL query is stored in the dataframe
print(df.head())

con.close()
```

Docs : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html?highlight=read%20sql%20query#pandas.read_sql_query

***EDIT***

Wait, I just re-read your question, the sources are already pandas dataframes???

Why are you pushing them to SQLite, just to read them back out again?  Just use `pd.merge()`?

```
df = pd.merge(
    table1,
    table2,
    how="left",
    on="id",
    suffixes=("_x", "_y"),
    copy=True
)
```

Docs : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html#pandas.merge

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out. What is the reason for this being faster, though?

Comment: @shenflow - In yours you query the database and place the results in to memory, then copy the results into another memory location (the pandas dataframe), then parse and copy them again to assign column names.  The above doesn't spam copies around in memory.

Comment: Regarding your question: I do quite complicated SQL merges, which I do not know how to replicate in pandas.

Comment: @shenflow - Then you should be asking how to use pandas to accomplish what you don't currently know how to do.  Shuffling 60M rows in and out of SQLite and Pandas is insane.  Use SAS, Or SQLite, or Pandas, don't move data between them just to avoid learning the syntax.  Learn Pandas (and many people here will help you) or don't use Pandas, but there's nothing I can do in SQL that I have been unable to do in Pandas.  *(Also note that SAS is built to be able to utilise multiple cpu cores, but Python is not.)*

Comment: I see. Nonetheless from what I understand, SQL is much more efficient than Pandas. I was of the opinion that it should still be more efficient to shuffling data in an out of pandas and sqlite than using pandas right away. The merges in pandas I tried to do took an insane amount of time.

Comment: Pandas expects you to format and sort the data for it, as it doesn't have indexes in quite the same way as SQL or SAS.  If you want to ask a question about how to speed up a particular use-case in Pandas, then give that as a concrete example in a new StackOverflow question.  If you believe that Pandas is not a suitable environment for processing the data, that begs the question why you're using Pandas.  But, shuffling millions of rows of data in and out of SQLite seems senseless.  This is now turning in to a discussion and training exercise, which is not what SO is for.